# CentOS 7 - Yum No match for argument: update

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm a new CentOS 7 user. I want to download LAMP on my centOs. When I'm typing;

```
sudo yum install update
```

There is an error occurs

```
Last metadata expiration check: 23:11:04 ago on Thu 16 Sep 2021 08:29:16 AM EDT.
No match for argument: update
Error: Unable to find a match: update
```

What should I do for the update the yum?

Comment: There is no such package in Centos repositories. You can run the following though: `yum install httpd mariadb-server php`  to install the necessary packages

Comment: The question is not about the php. I got struggle on the yum install update.

Comment: Well ok, then `I'm a new CentOS 7 user. I want to download LAMP on my centOs` is quite misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum install update` makes no sense. You're trying to install a package named "update".

Unlike apt with yum/dnf you normally don't need to update the packages database - yum/dnf does that automatically.

Simply run `yum install package_name` and you're good to go. If you don't know the exact name of a package, you could search for it using `yum search something`.

If you want to update all the packages in the system you simply run `yum update`.

Here's a nice guide how to install all the LAMP packages: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-7

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now. Appriciated